# Firebase app already exists

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I'm creating an Ionic 2 app and am using firebase and getting this error when running the app:

```
Firebase App named DEFAULT already exists [duplicate]
```

This is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
}
```

Of course this has my firebase information and not '...'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please check if this component is initialized more than once (with i.e. console log)? If so, then initializeApp would be called with already existing app. There can be multiple reasons for this, you will need to dig SO to debug it.

Comment: I checked, It is new clean project and I'm using Initialized just once in the code I posted.

Comment: As a workaround you can check if your app is in `firebase.apps` array.

Comment: where is this array located? I'm very new to this, sorry if stupid question.

Comment: No problem, check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#.apps.